# SQL Loop to increment numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm struggling coming up with a way to solve this answer. I want to start at a specific value and keep increasing it by 1 every time a new line.

For example, if I have  a table like so.

```
90    
93    
110   
87    
130  
Etc..
```

I want to select the number 87 and then keep incrementing up from there but also read if the incremented number is there and skip it.

I am just struggling with trying to put the right logic together in my head. I know I need a while loop to keep reading through the table but I can't think of the proper way to go about it. Just looking for some suggestions to push me in the right direction.

Edit: I am using T-SQL for MSFT SQL Server 2012.

Here is an example of what the output should look like

```
90    
93    
110   
87    
130  
88    
89    
91    
92    
94
```

It would skip over adding 90 and 93 because they already exist in the table.

I hope that makes sense to you guys.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results you are trying to get.  Also tag the question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: As a general SQL observation you should not think of the solution procedurally. While many dialects support iteration, in most cases a set (or possibly sequence) oriented approach will provide you with the correct result much more robustly. To get a better response to your question, provide a concrete example of both the input and output tables.

Comment: So, the point is to get all the numbers missing in a range?

Comment: Kinda. I'm trying to always get a display to increment the next order number in the range of 100-20,000 but there are too many random entries between 100-20,000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it all in one recursive CTE and I make it so you can use order by and guarantee your results are returned in the correct order.

For the recursion, you can either choose and start and end number or @desiredNumberOfNewValues(keep in mind, it doesn't account for repeats). Let me know if you have any questions or need anything else.

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (nums INT);
INSERT INTO @yourTable
    VALUES (90),(93),(110),(87),(130);


DECLARE @Specific_Number INT = 87;
DECLARE @Last_Number INT = 94;
DECLARE @DesiredNumberOfNewValues INT = 7;

WITH CTE_Numbers
AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS order_id,nums, 1 AS cnt
    FROM @yourTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  2, 
            CASE
                WHEN @Specific_Number + cnt NOT IN (SELECT * FROM @yourTable) --if it's not already in the table, return it
                    THEN @Specific_Number + cnt
                ELSE NULL -- if it is in the table, return NULL
            END,
            cnt + 1
    FROM CTE_Numbers
    WHERE   nums = @Specific_Number
            --OR (cnt > 1 AND @Specific_Number + cnt < @Last_Number) --beginning and end(option 1)
            OR (cnt > 1 AND cnt <= @DesiredNumberOfNewValues) --number of new values(option 2)
)

SELECT order_id,nums
FROM CTE_Numbers
WHERE nums IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY order_id,nums
```

Results:

```
order_id    nums
----------- -----------
1           87
1           90
1           93
1           110
1           130
2           88
2           89
2           91
2           92
2           94
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with some modifications by using Numbers table. In SQL Server, you could do the following. Assuming Test has the data. To create Numbers table, please refer to the following link.

http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/

```
SELECT n.Number,t.ColB
FROM Numbers n 
LEFT JOIN Test t
    ON n.Number = t.ColA
Where n.Number < (SELECT MAX(COLA) FROM Test t)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Numbers_CTE (Number)
AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number+1 FROM Numbers_CTE
)
SELECT top 10 *
FROM Numbers_CTE n
LEFT JOIN <TABLE> t ON t.ID=n.Number
WHERE t.ID IS NULL
AND n.Number BETWEEN 5 AND 100
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a system table you can use for numbers called `master..spt_values`.

**DECLARE sample TABLE**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id INT)
```

**INSERT statement**

```
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (90)   
                        ,(93)    
                        ,(110)   
                        ,(87)    
                        ,(130)
```

You can easily make a `UNION` to remove duplicates value you have in your table and `ORDER` it within a `CTE`

```
DECLARE @number INT = 87

;WITH C AS(
    SELECT Id, Row_Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id) AS Rn FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS Row_Id, Id FROM @tbl
        UNION
        SELECT 2 AS Row_Id, number
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE [type] = 'P'
        AND number >= @number
    ) t
)
SELECT Id FROM C
WHERE Rn = 1
ORDER BY Row_Id, Id
```

**Output**

```
Id
----
87
90
93
110
130
88
89
91
92
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
111
112
113
114
.
.
.
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9f73c/3)

Comment: Except your union doesn't work because your row_id's are different so you have repeat of 90 and 93 which the OP doesn't want.